# Calling a masm function from cpp

Tags: c++, linker, masm

I am working on a project where I want to implement some function using assembly, both 32 and 64 bit, my setup is Visual Studio 2015 community and using MSVC. I am trying to call a function implemented in assembly from my cpp code.

My assembly file and function looks like this:

```
IFDEF RAX
ELSE
.model flat, stdcall
ENDIF


.code

PUBLIC CheckParity

; bool CheckParity(size_t Result)
    CheckParity PROC

    IFDEF RAX

    mov     rax, 0
    add     rcx, 0
    jnp     jmp_over
    mov     rax, 1

    ELSE

    mov     eax, 0
    pop     ecx
    add     ecx, 0
    jnp     jmp_over
    mov     eax, 1

    ENDIF

jmp_over:
    ret
CheckParity ENDP

END
```

Declaration in header:

```
extern "C" bool CheckParity(size_t Result);
```

Calling the function:

```
CheckParity(SomeValue);
```

The error I get when compiling the project:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CheckParity referenced in function "public: virtual long __thiscall Emulation::_ASE_EMULATION_INSTANCE_FILE::ExecuteInstruction(struct Memory::_ASE_MEMORY_ACCESS *,unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?ExecuteInstruction@_ASE_EMULATION_INSTANCE_FILE@Emulation@@UAEJPAU_ASE_MEMORY_ACCESS@Memory@@PAEI@Z)   ase C:\Users\Alien\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\xed2_test\ase\ASEEmulation.obj 1
```

The weird thing here is that this compiles and links with no errors for 64 bit.
The problem only arises when linking for 32 bit.

I have read and tried the following posts with no luck:

[Calling a library made in MASM to C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23586145/4727279)

[Calling An Asm Function From C](https://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2008/08/15/calling-an-asm-function-from-c/)

Comment: Read the error message again, especially the name of the symbol it's looking for.

Comment: I guess you're implying that changing CheckParity to _CheckParity helps, I've just checked and it does not solve this.

Comment: Change `.model flat, stdcall` to `.model flat, c`

Comment: You did change it in the assembler file?

Comment: @Some programmer dude - yes, it did not help.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Petch - this worked, thanks :)

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to continue using `.model flat, stdcall`, prototype the function in C using `__stdcall`: `extern "C"  bool __stdcall CheckParity(size_t Result);`

Comment: @CodyGray This didn't work, I have tried it before aswell.